# Catalog Product View XML attribute insertion issue

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I've got this code in my catalog_category_view.xml file:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.condition" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" before="product.info.sku">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getCondition</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">condition</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">condition</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">CONDITION:</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="condition"</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

The Label "Condition" renders but the attribute value only returns the ID number and not the Dropdown value.

May I ask what I am missing?

Comment: Can refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113605/magento-2-what-is-at-call-for-in-layout-file?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Got the same problem with only being able to print the id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 - How to get attribute of product?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106809/magento-2-how-to-get-attribute-of-product)

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution here: [Magento 2 - How to get attribute of product?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106809/magento-2-how-to-get-attribute-of-product/120618)

```
<argument name="at_type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
```